# Laravel: Register events/listeners outside EventServiceProvider?

Tags: php, laravel

I hope this question is not duplicated.

In Laravel, how can I register events/listeners to that events outside `app/Providers/EventServiceProvider` file? Also, is it possible to register them on-the-fly?

Comment: registering them on the fly is no different then registering them in a service provider ... the event service provider is just a convenience to register these arrays for you, you can register events and listeners in any provider and any time after the framework has been booted

Comment: Failed to notice that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register your events, listeners, and subscribers in any Service Provider's `boot` method. The `EventServiceProvider` just provides convenience specifically for events, but it is just taking these arrays and spinning through them and registering them how you would manually do it anyway.

At any time after the framework has basically ran all the `register` methods of the Service Providers you can register events and listeners.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your frustration here.

I can share you my EventSubscriber that you only need to register this once in the Event Provider then you can register other events on the fly in this class once your platform is growing.

```
<?php

namespace App\Laravel\Jobs\Subscriber;

use App\Laravel\Models\{User,UserLogin,UserEngagement,UserDevice,UserPasswordReset};
use App\Laravel\Events\UserLogger;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher;
use Carbon,Mail,Str,DB;
class UserSubscriber
{

    public function onResetPassword($data){

        $user = $data->user;

        $user_password = UserPasswordReset::where('email',$user->email)->first();

        if(!$user_password){
            $user_password = new UserPasswordReset;
            $user_password->email = $user->email;
        }

        $user_password->token = Str::upper(Str::random(6));
        $user_password->created_at = Carbon::now();
        $user_password->save();
        DB::commit();

        $token = encrypt("{$user_password->email}__{$user_password->token}");

        $input['token'] = $token;

        Mail::send('emails.password', $input, function($message) use($user){
            $message->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject("Password Reset Request");
        });
    }

    public function registerDevice($data){
        $user = $data->user;

        if(strlen($data->device_id) > 0 AND strlen($data->device_reg_id) > 0){
            $device = UserDevice::where('user_id',$user->id)
                                ->where('device_id',$data->device_id)
                                ->first();

            if(!$device){
                $device = new UserDevice;
                $device->user_id = $user->id;
                $device->device_id = $data->device_id;
            }
            $device->device_reg_id = $data->device_reg_id;
            $device->device_brand = $data->device_brand;
            $device->device_brand_model = $data->device_brand_model;
            $device->device_platform = $data->device_platform;
            $device->device_platform_version = $data->device_platform_version;
            $device->is_login = 1;
            $device->save();
        }
        
    }
    
    /**
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function onLogin($data)
    {
        $user = $data->user;
        $last_login = UserLogin::where('user_id',$user->id)->orderBy('created_at',"DESC")->first();
        if(!$last_login OR ($last_login AND $last_login->created_at->diffInMinutes(Carbon::now()) >= 60)){
            $login = new UserLogin;
            $login->user_id = $user->id;
            $login->ip_address = $data->ip_address;
            $login->user_agent = $data->user_agent;
            $login->save();

            event('badge.login',(object)['user' => $user]);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Register the listeners for the subscriber.
     *
     * @param Dispatcher $events
     */
    public function subscribe($events)
    {
        $events->listen(
            'user.device',
            'App\Laravel\Jobs\Subscriber\UserSubscriber@registerDevice'
        );

        $events->listen(
            'user.login',
            'App\Laravel\Jobs\Subscriber\UserSubscriber@onLogin'
        );

        $events->listen(
            'user.reset_password',
            'App\Laravel\Jobs\Subscriber\UserSubscriber@onResetPassword'
        );
    }
}
```

Then on your EventServiceProvider there's a subscribe variable where you put this UserSubscriber Class

```
/**
     * The subscriber classes to register.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $subscribe = [
        \App\Laravel\Jobs\Subscriber\UserSubscriber::class,

    ];
```

This will save you a lot of  work and better  management of your events within your platform or project

Comment: I don't need to go through the subscriber from EventServiceProvider. I can register events on fly anywhere.

Comment: yes actually your right on that . however this is a good insight if your building or have plan to build a large project or platform.